# Bugzilla mail_delivery_method using TLS for Gmail

Tags: bugzilla

I installed the TLS as described on [this page](http://www.dawood.in/bugzilla_alerts_using_gmail.html) and verified that the package is installed.

I restarted the Apache server, logged in to BugZilla as admin and went to `Administration -> Parameters -> Email`.

I can't see the option for `SMTP::TLS` under `mail_delivery_method` as described in the article linked above. How do I enable this option?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone trying to set up Bugzilla's email feature to use Gmail on a windows machine, I just spent two and a half days at work with dawood's solution http://www.dawood.in/bugzilla_alerts_using_gmail.html, to no avail. My machine is running 64 bit Windows 7, And I eventually did find a solution, skip to the third paragraph for that. Here's why Dawood's solution won't work for most windows users:

Chances are, if you installed Bugzilla the by following the (awesome) tutorials, you installed ActivePerl. The Email::Send::SMTP::TLS perl package that Dawood's solution revolves around depends upon an Email::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained package, which, in turn, depends upon a Net::SSLeay package. (This is why, even after following Dawood's instructions and modifying Mailer.pm, no "SMTP::TLS" option appears in the drop down list. The dependencies aren't resolved.) The trouble is, Net::SSLeay will only install if it is compiled with THE SAME compiler you used to compile Perl. In addition, The documentation says: "Please do not even dream of copying a perl binary or installing perl binary from a package." Oh... whoops... ActivePerl is binary installed from a package. Since that won't work, here's what will.

To configure Bugzilla to send mail through Gmail's smtp server:

1. Download Glob's sendmail wrapper for windows at http://glob.com.au/sendmail/, and unzip
2. copy sendmail.exe and sendmail.ini to \usr\lib on the drive where the unix application is installed. So if Bugzilla is installed at C:\Bugzilla, create a 'usr' folder at the root level of the C: drive, with a 'lib' folder within that.
3. open up sendmail.ini.
4. within sendmail.ini copy and paste these values on the appropriate lines:

   - smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com:587
   - smtp_ssl=tls
   - auth_username=`<INSERT YOUR USERNAME HERE>`
   - auth_password=`<INSERT YOUR PASSWORD HERE>`
   - if your gmail server runs on a specific domain, make sure to uncomment and fill in the default_domain parameter.
5. now go to the Administration tab in Bugzilla, and select Parameters
6. Choose Email from the sidebar on the left.
7. In the pulldown menu under mail_delivery_method, select Sendmail.
8. You're done! Bugzilla will send email through gmail's smtp server.

Comment: Actually I was able to complete the instructions on dawood's website by installing the TLS module using CPAN. I've submitted an answer to this question.

Comment: same as Jesse's answer but copy all dll files along with ini and exe from sendmail.zip package

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was able to use dawood's method to send email from Windows.

http://www.dawood.in/bugzilla_alerts_using_gmail.html

I installed ActivePerl 5.16.1 32bit on Windows 7 64bit and used CPAN to install the `Email::Send::SMTP::TLS` module. From command line open cpan:

`C:\>cpan`

Then from within cpan, install the module:

`cpan> install Email::Send::SMTP::TLS`

Which should automatically install the dependency `Net::SMTP::TLS::ButMaintained`. Although `Net::SSLeay` was not installed, email still worked fine so I assume it's not a dependency anymore.

I then followed dawood's instructions to modify the Mailer.pm file. It has worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If we install `Net::SMTP::TLS`, we can see `SMTP::TLS` under `mail_ delivery_method`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in Mailer.pm and you should be able to see `SMTP::TLS` in the drop down list.

```
use Email::Send::SMTP::TLS;
```

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
./install-module.pl Email::Send::SMTP::TLS
```